# how to register onTouchListener on framelayout?

Tags: android, touch-event

I'm using FrameLayout to but some views above other views
and I want to register onTouchListener on this layout
I made the activity implements OnTouchListener
but "onTouch" method doesn't called when i touch the screen !!
this is my code

```
public class Mapactivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        TranslationListner , OnTouchListener {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);

FrameLayout mlayout;

    mlayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_root);

    File Tfile = this.getFilesDir();
    String Ttest = Tfile.getAbsolutePath();
    StorageEntity entity = new StorageEntity("map", ".xml", null, "Shine"
            + File.separator + "Sites", false);
    SiteMap map = null;
    try {
        map = MapParser.parseMap(entity, this);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    boolean fm = map.equals(null);
    MapView view = new MapView(this, map, 2);
    view.registerTranslationListner(Mapactivity.this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    mlayout.addView(view);
    AreaCentroid = map.getCenteroid(2);
    for (Area area : map.getFloorMap(2).getAreas()) {
        if (area.getAreaType() == Path.HALL) {
            ImageView hIcon = new ImageView(this);

            hIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hall);
            hIcon.setPadding(area.polygon.centeroid().x,
                    area.polygon.centeroid().y, 0, 0);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            hIcon.setLayoutParams(lp);
            icons.add(hIcon);
            mlayout.addView(hIcon);
        }

    }

    view.registerTranslationListner(Mapactivity.this);
mlayout.setOnTouchListener(Mapactivity.this);

}
```

Comment: Its hard to troubleshoot without your layout as well. I would suggest making sure your frame layout is enabled. Also, you can play around with the [`setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)) and [`android:descendantFocusability`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
the way to handle motion events is to make custom layout that extends framelayout
like that

```
public class MapLayout extends FrameLayout {
public MapLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MapLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MapLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

and then override onInterceptTouchEvent which called on any touch event happens on any child view in this layout

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        for (View childView : childerns) {

        }
        return false;
    }
```